# Using XPath expression with Simple XML

Tags: java, xml, simple-framework

```
<parent>
  <child>
    <child2>Some Text</child2>
  </child>
</parent>
```

Given the above xml. How can I make child2 element a direct member to parent?

```
@Root
class Parent {
  @Element
  String child2;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need specify an XPath expression for the field using the `Path` annotation.

```
@Root
class Parent {

    @Element
    @Path("child")
    String child2;

}
```

See also [*Mapping with XPath expressions*](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#xpath)